# Get predictions for all users with Surprise SVDpp algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine

I want to build a simple book recommender using `Surprise` library and *purchase/not purchase* as rating value (instead of the classical 1 to 5).

My problem here is that I want to train on my `whole dataset` so I can get predictions to `ALL users`, so I was checking this Surprise example `(examples/top_n_recommendations.py)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

from surprise import SVD
from surprise import Dataset    

def get_top_n(predictions, n=10):
            ...

# First train an SVD algorithm on the movielens dataset.
data = Dataset.load_builtin('ml-100k')
trainset = data.build_full_trainset()
algo = SVD()
algo.fit(trainset)

# Then predict ratings for all pairs (u, i) that are NOT in the training set.
testset = trainset.build_anti_testset()
predictions = algo.test(testset)

top_n = get_top_n(predictions, n=10)

# Print the recommended items for each user
for uid, user_ratings in top_n.items():
    print(uid, [iid for (iid, _) in user_ratings])
```

My doubt here is, if it trains on the whole dataset, why is it building an antitest?
How can I get recommendations for all users and at the same time train the algorithm on my whole dataset?

Answer (score 4):

Using the Surprise library, you can only get predictions for users within the trainingset. The antitestset consists of all pairs **(user,item)** that are not in the trainingset, hence it recommends items that the user has not been interacted with in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
You can use the model that is already fitted the data (algo), then you iterate over all users and all items to compute the estimated rating.

```
topn = defaultdict(list)
for uid in users:
    for iid in items:
        est = algo.predict(uid, iid).est
        topn[uid].append(iid,est)
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add a little explaination too :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a effective answer but maybe it can help.

```
df_predictions=pd.DataFrame([])
for i in users:
    df_tmp=pd.DataFrame([])
    df_pred['Estimate_Scores'] = df_pred['movie'].apply(lambda x: svd.predict(i, x).est)
    df_tmp['movie']=df_pred.sort_values('Estimate_Score', ascending=False).jobId.head(10).copy()
    df_tmp['user']=i
    df_predictions=df_predictions.append(df_tmp)
```